# Mule- Dataweave to insert new json field in the existing payload

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb

Sample Json Request

{
    "firstName": "George",
    "lastName": "Stephen"
}

Sample Json Response

{
   "id": "123",
   "firstName" : "George",
   "lastName" : "Stephen"
}

I want to do insert id value into Response Json without doing one to one mapping in dataweave ( I already have the working solution which does one to one mapping in dataweave and 2) using groovy component).

My Original JSON  Request is huge and lots of non-mandatory field that's why i am experimenting this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplest approach is to use `++` operator in dataweave like

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload ++  {id : "123"}
```

If you have to update child object you can use [`mapObject`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-operators#map-object).  This will iterate over each key.So based on key name you can use `++` to add field to child object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone needing this and has an **array** as the payload, you can do this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ((item, index) -> item ++ primary: true)
```

Replace the "primary: true" with whatever key-value pair you want.

[DW Playground Screenshot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dxI.png)

https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/ is great for playing around with dataweave code.

Comment: loved that DW Playground; thank u for sharing it, was my first time to know that there is such an easy way to test dataweave.