# How to add non-string value to object in Mulesoft

Tags: string, object, mule, dataweave

[image]
How to add a non-string value in the json object in dataweave. key2 : value2 is not a string and the output should not have inverted commas.
Expected Output:
{
"key": "value",
"key1": "vale1",
"key2": value2,
"key3": "value3"
}

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850629/mule-dataweave-to-insert-new-json-field-in-the-existing-payload

Comment: no, that also adds double quotes to value. I want the output value without double quotes for key2.

Comment: If the value is non-string, it will not add the quotes, but the way of adding it is same. Like this https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00005TViycSAD/how-to-add-a-new-key-value-pair-to-a-objectmap

Comment: I am actually hardcoding the value "value2" in the dataweave but in the json output value2 should not come as String with double quotes. I have added the screenshot in the question.

Comment: So you want a string value in JSON without quotes. That is not a valid JSON and so not supported by dataweave. Best bet would be to write it as a string and do some string manipulation to remove the quotes

Comment: @Uday why do you want to output it without quotes?

Comment: @aled target system is expecting one field value to be without quotes. I fixed it by converting json to string and removing the quotes as Harshank suggested.

Comment: Whatever the target system is expecting is not valid JSON.